# ionic content with scroll

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a view in ionic which has an image at the top and a scrollable list of messages. I want the image to stay on the screen while the list can be scrolled. Here is my current code:

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
    <img src="/myimage.png">

    <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: auto;" delegate-handle="postScroll">
        <div class="list">
        <a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="post in posts">
          <img ng-src="myimage.png">
          <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{post.content}}</p>
        </a>
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>
```

This works pretty well, i.e. the scroll does work and the image stays in place. But I am having trouble setting the height. If I have 100 posts, for example, I can only see 2-3 since the height container is not nearly large enough. Am I doing this correctly? How can I set a variable height for the number of posts? The user can add posts dynamically so this height needs to be able to change.

Comment: See if removing "height: auto" and putting, for example, 500px works.

Comment: that won't work, because i could have 5 posts or 50.

Comment: In fact if it will work, you will see the scroll function, it was only a test.

Answer (score 0):

I leave these codepen which will help you!

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" zooming="false" delegate-handle="horizontal2" horizontal-scroll-fix="mainScroll">
```

[example 1](http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/xGWBja?editors=100)

[example 2](http://codepen.io/jcsmith1859/pen/EoyqF?editors=110)

Comment: this isn't really what im looking for

Comment: Not want to run the height of the container independent of the amount of scroll post having?